# Install Ion3 Window Manager on OSX?

Tags: macos, window-manager, ion3

I want to install Ion3 on OSX. What is the easiest way?

I already tried

- Ports:
  `> port install ion3`
  Tells me something about license issues.
- Compiling the source:
  `> make`
  fails (I guess some missing dependencies or something..).
- fink and homebrew:
  they do not have it (or is there a way to "make them have it").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The README says you'll need gettext and Lua. You should be able to install those using MacPorts (`gettext` and `lua` ports). Then you'll need to modify the `system.mk` file to point to the installed Lua and perhaps other stuff. It will be trial and error and you'll need to read every error carefully. For example, I get this error when I run make right now:

```
…
In file included from output.c:23:
private.h:15:21: error: libintl.h: No such file or directory
…
make[1]: *** [output.o] Error 1
```

However, the file exists:

```
$ locate libintl.h
/opt/local/include/libintl.h
/opt/local/var/macports/software/gettext/0.18.1.1_2/opt/local/include/libintl.h
```

Another option is to look at an [older Portfile](http://trac.macports.org/log/trunk/dports/x11/ion3/Portfile) and follow the build process yourself, but note that it's for an older version of ion3. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks so much for the old Portfile hint. I got it to compile. Here ist my system.mk file: http://gist.github.com/598201 ... no idea yet, if the compiled thing works :)

Comment: @Julius: Good to hear.